# ChartJs + ie11 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, chart.js, internet-explorer-11

When i am trying to load my chart.js line graph with about 2000 points graph "crash" as seen in photo. It works in all browsers includin Edge but not in internet explorer 11. I would need your help with this problem. Image: [Randered graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToqOh.png).

Console doesnt return any error.

```
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 0;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var config = {
    data: lineChartData,

    options: {

        annotation: {
            annotations: [{
                type: 'line',
                mode: 'horizontal',
                scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                value: <?php echo $data['max']; ?>,

                borderColor: 'rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)',
                borderWidth: 0.5
            }, {
                type: 'line',
                mode: 'horizontal',
                scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                value: <?php echo $data['min']; ?>,
                borderColor: 'rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)',
                borderWidth: 0.5
            }]
        },
        responsive: true,
        elements: {
            point: {
                radius: 0,
                pointHitRadius: 1
            }
        },
        hoverMode: 'index',
        stacked: false,
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false
        },

        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormats: {
                        'millisecond': 'DD MMM',
                        'second': 'DD MMM',
                        'minute': 'DD MMM',
                        'hour': 'DD MMM',
                        'day': 'DD MMM',
                        'week': 'DD MMM',
                        'month': 'DD MMM',
                        'quarter': 'DD MMM',
                        'year': 'DD MMM',
                    },
                    unitStepSize: 1,
                    unit: 'day',
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                }
            }]

        }
    }
};



config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.borderColor = colr;
    dataset.backgroundColor = colr;

});


window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx, config);
```

I allready tried to change Doctype, checking code in JSHint but it doesn't work.

Comment: They might have dropped IE11 support...

Comment: You should drop IE support too.

Comment: I know that, but client don't want to...:S. And no they didn't drop support.

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html works just fine on IE11, so I'd start removing your config options until its barebones and it works.

Comment: @CodyG. Yeah, thats works fine but ... here is my code and you can try: https://pastebin.com/ScLXAccd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some of your data, e.g.,

`{y:25.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:37:38\n"}`

You have an extra `\n` which is causing the date to be invalid, remove this and the graph appears to work as intended.

I modified some border widths.

```html
  <head>
    <title>Test
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === undefined) {
        console.log("max increase;");
        Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991;
      }
      if (Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER === undefined) {
        Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER = -9007199254740991;
        console.log("min idecrease;");
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === undefined) {
        console.log("max increase;");
        Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991;
      }
      if (Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER === undefined) {
        Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER = -9007199254740991;
        console.log("min idecrease;");
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:95%;">
      <canvas id="canvas" style="height:400px;">
      </canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
      Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 0;
      if (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER === undefined) {
        console.log("max increase;");
        Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991;
      }
      if (Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER === undefined) {
        Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER = -9007199254740991;
        console.log("min idecrease;");
      }
      var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
      var yourImage = new Image();
      yourImage.src ="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
      yourImage.width ="2";
      yourImage.height ="15";
      var lineChartData = {
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "0",
            fill: false,
            hidden: true,
            borderWidth: 3,
            data:[{
              y:25.3,x:"2018-04-18 12:16:02"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:23:30"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:30:35"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:37:38"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:44:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.8,x:"2018-04-18 12:51:45"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.7,x:"2018-04-18 12:58:50"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:00:37"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:05:56"}
                  ,{
                    y:26,x:"2018-04-18 13:09:49"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:10:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:26,x:"2018-04-18 13:11:35"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.7,x:"2018-04-18 13:12:28"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.8,x:"2018-04-18 13:13:21"}
                  ,{
                    y:26,x:"2018-04-18 13:16:52"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.2,x:"2018-04-18 13:20:23"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.2,x:"2018-04-18 13:27:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.2,x:"2018-04-18 13:34:44"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.2,x:"2018-04-18 13:41:47"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:42:40"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:48:50"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:55:51"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.4,x:"2018-04-18 14:02:53"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.5,x:"2018-04-18 14:09:55"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.6,x:"2018-04-18 14:11:40"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.6,x:"2018-04-18 14:16:57"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.6,x:"2018-04-18 14:23:59"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.7,x:"2018-04-18 14:31:01"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.7,x:"2018-04-18 14:38:05"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.7,x:"2018-04-18 14:45:07"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.8,x:"2018-04-18 14:52:10"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.8,x:"2018-04-18 14:59:12"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.8,x:"2018-04-18 15:06:14"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.8,x:"2018-04-18 15:13:17"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.8,x:"2018-04-18 15:20:20"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.8,x:"2018-04-18 15:27:23"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.8,x:"2018-04-18 15:34:25"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.9,x:"2018-04-18 15:37:58"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.9,x:"2018-04-18 15:41:29"}
                  ,{
                    y:27,x:"2018-04-18 15:48:34"}
                  ,{
                    y:27,x:"2018-04-18 15:56:25"}
                  ,{
                    y:27,x:"2018-04-18 16:03:29"}
                  ,{
                    y:27.1,x:"2018-04-18 16:09:38"}
                  ,{
                    y:27.1,x:"2018-04-18 16:10:31"}
                  ,{
                    y:27.1,x:"2018-04-18 16:17:34"}
                  ,{
                    y:27.1,x:"2018-04-18 16:24:38"}
                  ,{
                    y:27.1,x:"2018-04-18 16:31:40"}
                  ,{
                    y:27.2,x:"2018-04-18 16:38:43"}
                 ]
          }
          , {
            label: "2",
            fill: false,
            hidden: true,
            borderWidth: 3,
            data:[{
              y:32.4,x:"2018-04-18 12:16:02"}
                  ,{
                    y:32.7,x:"2018-04-18 12:17:48"}
                  ,{
                    y:32.2,x:"2018-04-18 12:18:40"}
                  ,{
                    y:32,x:"2018-04-18 12:20:27"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.5,x:"2018-04-18 12:23:30"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.2,x:"2018-04-18 12:27:55"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.2,x:"2018-04-18 12:30:35"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.5,x:"2018-04-18 12:35:52"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.5,x:"2018-04-18 12:37:38"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.7,x:"2018-04-18 12:44:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.8,x:"2018-04-18 12:45:35"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:51:45"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.3,x:"2018-04-18 12:57:57"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.4,x:"2018-04-18 12:58:50"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.9,x:"2018-04-18 13:00:37"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:01:30"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.9,x:"2018-04-18 13:05:02"}
                  ,{
                    y:27.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:05:56"}
                  ,{
                    y:27.7,x:"2018-04-18 13:06:49"}
                  ,{
                    y:29.5,x:"2018-04-18 13:07:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.8,x:"2018-04-18 13:09:49"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.5,x:"2018-04-18 13:10:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.8,x:"2018-04-18 13:11:35"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.5,x:"2018-04-18 13:12:28"}
                  ,{
                    y:26.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:12:28"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.8,x:"2018-04-18 13:13:21"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.2,x:"2018-04-18 13:15:59"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:16:52"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:18:37"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:20:23"}
                  ,{
                    y:25,x:"2018-04-18 13:21:16"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:23:01"}
                  ,{
                    y:24.8,x:"2018-04-18 13:23:54"}
                  ,{
                    y:24.5,x:"2018-04-18 13:24:11"}
                  ,{
                    y:24.2,x:"2018-04-18 13:26:49"}
                  ,{
                    y:24.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:27:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:24.9,x:"2018-04-18 13:28:35"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.1,x:"2018-04-18 13:30:20"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:32:58"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.1,x:"2018-04-18 13:34:44"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:36:30"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.9,x:"2018-04-18 13:38:16"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:40:01"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:40:54"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.5,x:"2018-04-18 13:41:47"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:42:40"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:43:33"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.1,x:"2018-04-18 13:44:25"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:46:11"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:47:57"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.5,x:"2018-04-18 13:48:50"}
                  ,{
                    y:25.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:52:20"}
                  ,{
                    y:25,x:"2018-04-18 13:53:13"}
                  ,{
                    y:24.7,x:"2018-04-18 13:54:06"}
                  ,{
                    y:24.7,x:"2018-04-18 13:55:51"}
                 ]
          }
          , {
            label: "1",
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 3,
            data:[{
              y:9.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:16:02"}
                  ,{
                    y:9.6,x:"2018-04-18 12:16:55"}
                  ,{
                    y:9.2,x:"2018-04-18 12:19:33"}
                  ,{
                    y:8.8,x:"2018-04-18 12:22:37"}
                  ,{
                    y:8.7,x:"2018-04-18 12:23:30"}
                  ,{
                    y:8.6,x:"2018-04-18 12:24:23"}
                  ,{
                    y:8.3,x:"2018-04-18 12:27:02"}
                  ,{
                    y:8.1,x:"2018-04-18 12:28:49"}
                  ,{
                    y:7.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:30:35"}
                  ,{
                    y:7.8,x:"2018-04-18 12:32:21"}
                  ,{
                    y:7.6,x:"2018-04-18 12:35:00"}
                  ,{
                    y:7.5,x:"2018-04-18 12:37:38"}
                  ,{
                    y:7.3,x:"2018-04-18 12:41:11"}
                  ,{
                    y:7.1,x:"2018-04-18 12:43:49"}
                  ,{
                    y:7.1,x:"2018-04-18 12:44:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.9,x:"2018-04-18 12:51:45"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.8,x:"2018-04-18 12:53:31"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.7,x:"2018-04-18 12:58:50"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.6,x:"2018-04-18 13:00:37"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.5,x:"2018-04-18 13:05:56"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:13:21"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:20:23"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.5,x:"2018-04-18 13:25:57"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:27:42"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.4,x:"2018-04-18 13:34:44"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:39:08"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:41:47"}
                  ,{
                    y:6.3,x:"2018-04-18 13:48:50"}
                 ]
          }
          ,{
            label: "6",
            data: [{
              y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 12:16:02"}
                   ,{
                     y:"1",x:"2018-04-18 12:20:52"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 12:21:45"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 12:23:30"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 12:30:35"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 12:37:38"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 12:44:42"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 12:51:45"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 12:58:50"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:05:56"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:13:21"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:20:23"}
                   ,{
                     y:"1",x:"2018-04-18 13:24:00"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:25:04"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:27:42"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:34:44"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:41:47"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:48:50"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 13:55:51"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:02:53"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:09:55"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:16:57"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:23:59"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:31:01"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:38:05"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:45:07"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:52:10"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 14:59:12"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 15:06:14"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 15:13:17"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 15:20:20"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 15:27:23"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 15:34:25"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 15:41:29"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 15:48:34"}
                   ,{
                     y:"1",x:"2018-04-18 15:55:07"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 15:56:25"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:03:29"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:10:31"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:17:34"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:24:38"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:31:40"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:38:43"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:45:45"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:52:47"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 16:59:49"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 17:06:52"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 17:13:54"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 17:20:55"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 17:27:59"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 17:35:01"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 17:42:03"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 17:49:06"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 17:56:08"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:03:11"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:10:12"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:17:16"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:24:18"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:31:20"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:38:23"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:45:25"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:52:28"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 18:59:32"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 19:06:34"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 19:13:37"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 19:20:40"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 19:27:43"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 19:34:46"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 19:41:49"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 19:48:53"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 19:55:57"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:02:59"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:10:02"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:17:04"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:24:06"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:31:08"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:38:11"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:45:13"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:52:15"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 20:59:16"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 21:06:19"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 21:13:21"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 21:20:27"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 21:27:29"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 21:34:32"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 21:41:35"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 21:48:36"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 21:55:38"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:02:41"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:09:44"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:16:47"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:23:51"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:30:53"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:37:57"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:45:01"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:52:05"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 22:59:08"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 23:06:12"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 23:13:15"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 23:20:17"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 23:27:19"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 23:34:21"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 23:41:25"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 23:48:27"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-18 23:55:30"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:02:33"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:09:38"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:16:40"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:23:43"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:30:47"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:37:50"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:44:52"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:51:54"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 00:58:56"}
                   ,{
                     y:"0",x:"2018-04-19 01:05:59"}
                  ],
            borderWidth: 3,
            hiddenLegend: true,
            fill: false,
            pointStyle:['',yourImage,'','','','','','','','','','',yourImage,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',yourImage,'','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',yourImage,'','','','','','',yourImage,'','','',yourImage,'','','','','','','','',yourImage,'',yourImage,'','','',yourImage,'','','',yourImage,'','',yourImage,'','','','','','','','','','','','',]}
          ,],
        yHighlightRange : {
          begin: 2,
          end: 8    }
      };
      var config={
        data: lineChartData,
        options: {
          annotation: {
            annotations: [{
              type: 'line',
              mode: 'horizontal',
              scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
              value: 8,
              label: {
                content: "Ln2",
                enabled: true,
                position:'left',
              }
              ,
              borderColor: 'rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)',
              borderWidth: 3
            }
                          ,{
                            type: 'line',
                            mode: 'horizontal',
                            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                            label: {
                              content: "Lin1",
                              enabled: true,
                              position:'left',
                            }
                            ,
                            value: 2,
                            borderColor: 'rgba(231, 76, 60,1.0)',
                            borderWidth: 3
                          }
                         ]
          }
          ,
          responsive: true,
          elements: {
            point: {
              radius: 0, pointHitRadius: 1}
          }
          ,
          hoverMode: 'index',
          stacked: false,         
          tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false
          }
          ,
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                displayFormats: {
                  'millisecond': 'DD MMM',
                  'second': 'DD MMM',
                  'minute': 'DD MMM',
                  'hour': 'DD MMM',
                  'day': 'DD MMM',
                  'week': 'DD MMM',
                  'month': 'DD MMM',
                  'quarter': 'DD MMM',
                  'year': 'DD MMM',
                }
                ,
                unitStepSize: 1,
                unit: 'day',
              }
              ,
              gridLines : {
                display : false,
              }
            }
                   ],
            yAxes: [{
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                show: true,
                labelString: "Value"
              }
              ,ticks: {
                suggestedMin:2 -5,
                suggestedMax:8 +5,
              }
              ,
            }
                   ]
          }
        }
      };
      var randomColorFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      };
      var randomColor = function(opacity) {
        return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '1.0') + ')';
      };
      config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        var colr=randomColor(0.4);
        dataset.borderColor = colr;
        dataset.backgroundColor = colr;
      }
                                  );
      window.myLine = Chart.Line(ctx,config);
    </script>
    </script>
  <a  href="http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/multi-axis.html">LINK
  </a>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that Compatibility mode for IE 11 when turned on stops chart.js.  Turned off compatibility mode and works.